# gorilla mux subrouter empty path

Tags: go, gorilla

i want to create a /user subrouter as following

```
user := app.Router.PathPrefix("/user").Subrouter()
user.HandleFunc("/create", (&controllers.User{c}).Create)
user.HandleFunc("", (&controllers.User{c}).Create).Methods("POST")
user.HandleFunc("", (&controllers.User{c}).FindAll).Methods("GET")
user.HandleFunc("/{id}", (&controllers.User{c}).Update).Methods("PUT")
user.HandleFunc("/{id}", (&controllers.User{c}).Destroy).Methods("DELETE")
user.HandleFunc("/{id}", (&controllers.User{c}).FindOne).Methods("GET")
```

the problem is the domain/user doenst work. i can do this

```
user.HandleFunc("/", (&controllers.User{c}).Create).Methods("POST")
```

but then it only matches domain/user/
any idea how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If setting strict slash to true won't work for you, then you may have to handle the routes without a slash in the router rather than using a subrouter:

```
app.Router.HandleFunc("/user", (&controllers.User{c}).Create).Methods("POST")
app.Router.HandleFunc("/user", (&controllers.User{c}).FindAll).Methods("GET")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the router's [strict slash](http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.StrictSlash) to `true` so that `/domain/user` redirects to `/domain/user/`.

You would need to have at the top:

```
app.Router.StrictSlash(true)
```

and set the routes to:

```
user.HandleFunc("/", (&controllers.User{c}).Create).Methods("POST")
user.HandleFunc("/", (&controllers.User{c}).FindAll).Methods("GET")
```

Comment: Its not a good option for me to use cause it wil loose performance and it dont work for my post requests